# Large background image without horizontal scrollbars

Tags: css, background, position

I would like to reproduce the Apple large background effect (apple.com)
The background, while larger than the browser, does not make the horizontal scrollbar appear, and when we make the browser smaller than 1024px, then the background is locked on the left, adopting the normal behavior of a normal 1024px wide website, while online solutions only offer to center the background at all times.
Anyone knows how to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

set Background from CSS,

following html sets background without making horizontal scrollbar appear

```
html { 
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;     
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Well, firstly, it's one of the examples I talked about in my question, in which the background is centered at all times. Secondly, I think the answer I am looking for would be based on containers in containers, overflows... Just look at this page http://www.apple.com/your-verse/, the background image is centered, up until the point the browser width becomes smaller than 1024px, then it's not centered anymore, it's locked on the left with the rest of the website.